# maxResult is not working when doing a tasks.tasklists.list

Tags: ios, google-tasks-api, google-tasks, google-api-objc-client

First of all the documentation is wrong. It says that the default value for MaxResult is 100, but if I do a query ( on my account with 31 lists) on the Tasks API explorer without setting the MaxResult parameter, I always get 20 items back with a nextPageToken to be able to query the next 20 items.

If I set the maxResults to 1, 10 or 100 nothing changes, I still get always 20 items.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks

UPDATE :  This is how my query is made:

```
...
GTLQueryTasks* query = [self createQueryForCmd:cmd];
self.tasksTicket = [self.tasksService executeQuery:query  completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
...// handle the response
 }
... 

// This helper method creates a query for each type of operation,I have omitted operations other than lists.list

-(GTLQueryTasks*)createQueryForCmd:(SyncCommand*) cmd{
    NSString* listId = cmd.listId;
    GTLQueryTasks *query = nil;
    GTLObject* localObject = nil;
    NSString* transactionETag = nil;
    switch (cmd.syncOperation) {
            /*------------Lists operations---------------------------------*/
        case SyncOpListsList:{
            query =  [GTLQueryTasks queryForTasklistsList];
            query.maxResults = 100;
            break;
        }
.....
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? Maybe you missed something. Try to check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/quickstart/ios).

Comment: The code is in line with the documentation examples, but even using the tasks API explorer is possible to reproduce the problem. But maybe I'm missing something obvious.